# I need to find the RECENT,MAX, SUM as dataset values joining two tables in one select query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables 'Receipt Table:'  and 'Person Table:'
I need to find the result set for these values 
SUM amount,  MAXIMUM amt paid as of today, MAXIMUM amt paid_DATE as of today,
RECENT amt paid as of today, RECENT amt paid_DATE as of today.

Here is the Tabluler format below.

### RECEIPT TABLE:

```
ReceiptID   Receipt_Date    AmountPaid  PersonID
R001    1/1/2011    $50     P003
R002    1/2/2011    $20.20  P001
R003    1/2/2011    $35     P005
R004    1/4/2011    $17     P002
R005    1/10/2011   $89.20  P003
R006    1/11/2011   $10     P001
R007    1/11/2011   $9.15   P007
R008    1/12/2011   $5.45   P002
R009    1/20/2011   $65     P006
R010    1/23/2011   $20     P004
R011    1/29/2011   $10     P003
```

### PERSON TABLE:

```
PersonID    PersonName
P001    A_person
P002    B_person
P003    C_person
P004    D_person
P005    E_person
P006    F_person
P007    G_person
P008    H_person
```

### OUTPUT RESULT:

```
PersonID    PersonName  Sum(Amtpaid)    RECENT(AmountPaid)  RECENT(Amtpaid_ReceiptDate) Max (Amt Receipt_paid as of today)  Max (amt receipt paid Date as of today)
P001    A_Person    $30.20  $10     1/11/2011   $20.20  1/2/2011
P002    B_person    $22.45  $5.45   1/12/2011   $17     1/4/2011
P003    C_person    $149.20     $10     1/29/2011   $89.20  1/10/2011
P004    D_person    $20     $20     1/23/2011   $20     1/23/2011
P005    E_person    $35     $35     1/2/2011    $35     1/2/2011
P006    F_person    $65     $65     1/20/2011   $65     1/20/2011
P007    G_person    $9.15   $9.15   1/11/2011   $9.15   1/11/2011
```

Comment: How exactly do you define "recent"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not on a computer where I can test this code, but maybe you can try this:

```
;WITH Receipts AS
(
    SELECT  *, 
            SUM(AmountPaid) OVER(PARTITION BY PersonID) SumAmount, 
            MAX(AmountPaid) OVER(PARTITION BY PersonID) MaxAmount,
            MAX(Receipt_Date) OVER(PARTITION BY PersonID) RecentPaidDate
    FROM ReceiptTable
)

SELECT  P.PersonId, P.PersonName, 
        MIN(SumAmount) SumAmount,
        MIN(CASE WHEN Receipt_Date = RecentPaidDate THEN AmountPaid END) RecentAmountPaid,
        MIN(RecentPaidDate) RecentPaidDate,
        MIN(MaxAmount) MaxAmount,
        MIN(CASE WHEN AmountPaid = MaxAmount THEN Receipt_Date END) MaxAmountReceiptDate
FROM PersonTable P
JOIN Receipts R
ON R.PersonId = P.PersonID
GROUP BY P.PersonId, P.PersonName
```

Anyway, if you use the code before, you should be aware that it returns the `MIN` ReceiptDate in case that the MaxAmountPaid is repeated (meaning that it has 2 records that are the same amount and the MaxAmountPaid).

Comment: Hi Eric Petroelje
The 'RECENT' i mean the latest/new one from the payments per personID

Comment: Hi Lamak,  Your answer is excellent.  The result set what i wanted is accurate.  You are such an intellectual you solved my difficulty in getting the answer so quick and that too without a computer upfront.  I just slightly made some modification to get the MAX for the 'MaxAmountReceiptDAte'  and group by personID, personNAme

Comment: @desi You are welcome. You are right, I absolutely forgot about the GROUP BY. Glad you could make it work

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Select personId, PersonName,
    Sum(r.amountPaid) TotalPaid,
    Max(m.amountPaid) MaxPaid,
    Max(m.Receipt_Date) MaxpaidDate,
    Max(x.amountPaid) recentPaid,
    Max(x.Receipt_Date) recentPaidDate

From Person p
   Left Join receipt r on r.PersonId = p.personId
   Left join receipt x 
       On x.personId = p.personId
           And x.Receipt_Date  =
              (Select Max(Receipt_Date)
               From Receipt
               Where personId = x.PersonId)
   Left join receipt m 
       On m.ReceiptId = 
         (Select Max(ReceiptId)
          From Receipt
           Where personId = m.PersonId 
              And amountPaid = 
                 (Select Max(amountPaid)
                  From Receipt
                  Where personId = m.PersonId))
Group By personId, PersonName
```

Comment: Hi Charles Bretana,   Thank you so much for your answer but i am getting the sum amt double in some situations for 'P001' if i run the query i am getting sum amt as '$60.40' which should be '$30.20'

Comment: ahhh there are probably more than one record with the same max amount, causing a cartesian product (doubling ot tripling the rows) I will fix that...

Answer (score 1):

Something like...

```
select 
p.PersonID,
p.PersonName,
sum(AmountPaid),
(select top 1 AmountPaid from RECEIPT where PersonID = p.PersonID Order By Receipt_Date Desc) AS recentPaidAmt,
(select top 1 Receipt_Date from RECEIPT where PersonID = p.PersonID Order By Receipt_Date Desc) AS recentPaidDate,
(select top 1 AmountPaid from RECEIPT where PersonID = p.PersonID Order By AmountPaid Desc) AS maxRecentPaidAmt,
(select top 1 Receipt_Date from RECEIPT where PersonID = p.PersonID Order By AmountPaid Desc) AS maxRecentPaidDate
from RECEIPT r, PERSON p 
where p.PersonID = r.PersonID
group by p.PersonID
```

Comment: Hi John K,  Thanks for your anwswer but i am getting the sum(amountpaid) as doubling eg;- 'P001' if i run the query i am getting sum amt as '$60.40' which should be '$30.20'

Comment: I left off a group by statement.